# How to load two external files in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

To load one TopoJson file in D3 (I'm using version 7), it's as simple as:

```
d3.json("file01.json").then(function(topology) {
```

To load two files in previous versions you could use for example in version 6:

```
Promise.all([
    d3.json("file01.json"),
    d3.json("file02.json", function(d) {
        data.set(d.code, +d.pop)
    })
]).then(function(loadData){
```

and in version 4, for example:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "file01.json")
  .defer(d3.json, "file02.json", function(d) { data.set(d.code, +d.pop); })
  .await(ready);
```

I tried both in version 7 and received the notice that promise or queue are not a function. So I interpreted that in version 7 there's another way to load two external files.

Thanks for any help which I couldn't find until now, despite searching all over the in Internet. There's a lot of material about version 3 to 6, but much less to version 7.

Comment: It's very strange that `Promise` is giving you an error, because that has nothing to do with D3 whatever its version, `Promise` is a standard built-in object in Javascript.

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado , I've seen lots of your posts overhere in stackoverflow (thanks for that), as I'm learning D3 and having a lot of doubts, mainly on account of using v.7 that still have less questions/discussions than previous versions and the modifications from one to another are not well documented. I just did what Shreshth sugested, but now I receive this error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: Promisse is not defined. :-\

Comment: Good to know. Just fyi, `d3.json` never accepted a row function, in any version.

Comment: Sure! I meant using queue, than using promise. Do you know a place where we can see something like a from -> to table of these kind of modifications in the different versions? It would be very helpful as I don't really understand observable....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`d3.json`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) in d3 v7 returns a promise, so what you wrote is almost correct. Just that the second argument isn't for manipulating data (it's for passing additional options to the fetch call: see [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)). d3.json uses the browser's inbuilt fetch() API.

To manipulate data you will have to do it in the then callback function.

```js
Promise.all([
    d3.json('file01.json'),
    d3.json('file02.json')
]).then(function([data01, data02]){

  // manipulate data here
  // data01
  // data02
})
```

See working example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/shreshthmohan/pen/bGojyOw) Check console for data being logged after being fetched.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shreshth! It's importing both data now. I tried to manipulate the data as you said, but somehow it's not working. Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637426/how-to-extract-and-concatenate-two-values-from-two-different-external-json-files