# How to extract and concatenate two values from two different external JSON files

Tags: javascript, json

I was able to plot a choropleth map using D3.js version 7, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dbahiense/0nmyp2cj/193/).
Now I'd like to get an extra external data to complement it.
I saw a lot of examples, but I'm kind of stuck now as the majority of examples are from previous versions that just don't work with the latest one no matter what I try.

The most important part of the js code which differs from the original is the following:

```
// topoJSON and election data paths
const topoJSONdata = "map.json";
const electionJSON = "election.json";

// load topoJSON and election JSON data
Promise.all([
    d3.json(topoJSONdata), // loads topoJSONdata a.k.a. map.json
    d3.json(electionJSON)  // loads electionJSON a.k.a. election.json
]).then(function([topology, data]){

    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.BRUF).features)
        .enter().append("path")

        .style("fill", function(d){
            console.log(d.properties.codarea) // this gives us the expected codarea value
--->        console.log(d.results.tt_nominais) // this is undefined WHY??? <---

            // pull data for this map region
            d.results.tt_nominais = data.get(d.properties.codarea) || 0
            // set the color
            return colorScale(d.results.tt_nominais);
        })

    .attr("d", path)
```

The part of loading two external files is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70629019/how-to-load-two-external-files-in-d3-js-version-7/70630081#70630081).
The problem occurs specially in this part:

```
    .style("fill", function(d){
        console.log(d.properties.codarea) // this gives us the expected codarea value
        console.log(d.results.tt_nominais) // this is undefined WHY??? <---

        // pull data for this map region
        d.results.tt_nominais = data.get(d.properties.codarea) || 0
        // set the color
        return colorScale(d.results.tt_nominais);
    })
```

The **map.json** file has the following structure:

```
"objects":{
    "BRUF":{
        "type":"GeometryCollection",
        "geometries":[{
            "arcs":[[0,1,2,3]],
            "type":"Polygon",
            "properties":{"codarea":"31"}
        },
        {
            "arcs":[[-1,4,5]],
            "type":"Polygon",
            "properties":{"codarea":"32"}
        },
        {
            "arcs":[[6,-2,-6,7,8,9]],
            "type":"Polygon",
            "properties":{"codarea":"33"}
        },{
            "arcs":[[10,-9,11]],
            "type":"Polygon",
            "properties":{"codarea":"35"}
        } etc.
```

[Here](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v3/malhas/paises/BR?formato=application/json&qualidade=minima&intrarregiao=UF) you can see the file in its entireness. **The election.json** is like the following:

```
{
    "president":[
        {
            "cd_ibge":"32",
            "sg_uf":"ES",
            "results":[
                {
                    "nr_partido":17,
                    "sg_partido":"PSL",
                    "nm_partido":"Partido Social Liberal",
                    "tt_nominais":"2244262"
                },
                {
                    "nr_partido":13,
                    "sg_partido":"PT",
                    "nm_partido":"Partido dos Trabalhadores",
                    "tt_nominais":"991736"
                },
                {
                    "nr_partido":12,
                    "sg_partido":"PDT",
                    "nm_partido":"Partido Democr?tico Trabalhista",
                    "tt_nominais":"391106"
                },
                {
                    "nr_partido":45,
                    "sg_partido":"PSDB",
                    "nm_partido":"Partido da Social Democracia Brasileira",
                    "tt_nominais":"158098"
                } etc.
            ]
        },
        {
            "cd_ibge":"33",
            "sg_uf":"RJ",
            "results":[{"nr_partido":17,"sg_partido":"PSL","nm_partido":"Partido Social Liberal","tt_nominais":"10215470"},{"nr_partido":12,"sg_partido":"PDT","nm_partido":"Partido Democr?tico Trabalhista","tt_nominais":"2600584"},{"nr_partido":13,"sg_partido":"PT","nm_partido":"Partido dos Trabalhadores","tt_nominais":"2510850"},{"nr_partido":51,"sg_partido":"PATRI","nm_partido":"Patriota","tt_nominais":"422888"},{"nr_partido":45,"sg_partido":"PSDB","nm_partido":"Partido da Social Democracia Brasileira","tt_nominais":"416650"},{"nr_partido":30,"sg_partido":"NOVO","nm_partido":"Partido Novo","tt_nominais":"278416"},{"nr_partido":18,"sg_partido":"REDE","nm_partido":"Rede Sustentabilidade","tt_nominais":"261588"},{"nr_partido":15,"sg_partido":"MDB","nm_partido":"Movimento Democr?tico Brasileiro","tt_nominais":"154666"},{"nr_partido":50,"sg_partido":"PSOL","nm_partido":"Partido Socialismo e Liberdade","tt_nominais":"115692"},{"nr_partido":19,"sg_partido":"PODE","nm_partido":"Podemos","tt_nominais":"83088"},{"nr_partido":16,"sg_partido":"PSTU","nm_partido":"Partido Socialista dos Trabalhadores Unificado","tt_nominais":"12010"},{"nr_partido":54,"sg_partido":"PPL","nm_partido":"Partido P?tria Livre","tt_nominais":"5612"},{"nr_partido":27,"sg_partido":"DC","nm_partido":"Democracia Crist?\";\"280000050639","tt_nominais":"0"}]
        },
        {
            "cd_ibge":"35",
            "sg_uf":"SP",
            "results":[{"nr_partido":17,"sg_partido":"PSL","nm_partido":"Partido Social Liberal","tt_nominais":"24756024"},{"nr_partido":13,"sg_partido":"PT","nm_partido":"Partido dos Trabalhadores","tt_nominais":"7667964"},{"nr_partido":12,"sg_partido":"PDT","nm_partido":"Partido Democr?tico Trabalhista","tt_nominais":"5300880"},{"nr_partido":45,"sg_partido":"PSDB","nm_partido":"Partido da Social Democracia Brasileira","tt_nominais":"4448098"},{"nr_partido":30,"sg_partido":"NOVO","nm_partido":"Partido Novo","tt_nominais":"2124236"},{"nr_partido":51,"sg_partido":"PATRI","nm_partido":"Patriota","tt_nominais":"549344"},{"nr_partido":15,"sg_partido":"MDB","nm_partido":"Movimento Democr?tico Brasileiro","tt_nominais":"535450"},{"nr_partido":18,"sg_partido":"REDE","nm_partido":"Rede Sustentabilidade","tt_nominais":"524100"},{"nr_partido":50,"sg_partido":"PSOL","nm_partido":"Partido Socialismo e Liberdade","tt_nominais":"374902"},{"nr_partido":19,"sg_partido":"PODE","nm_partido":"Podemos","tt_nominais":"355898"},{"nr_partido":16,"sg_partido":"PSTU","nm_partido":"Partido Socialista dos Trabalhadores Unificado","tt_nominais":"24868"},{"nr_partido":54,"sg_partido":"PPL","nm_partido":"Partido P?tria Livre","tt_nominais":"14870"},{"nr_partido":27,"sg_partido":"DC","nm_partido":"Democracia Crist?\";\"280000050639","tt_nominais":"0"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

My idea is to somehow concatenate both files through **codarea** from map.json and **cd_ibge** from election.js that have exactly the same value and change colors on the map according to the values os **tt_nominais** from election.js as well.

With a previous version I was able to do that (like in the above mentioned link), but not with version 7.

**====== EDIT ======**

After the very valuable comments from Ouroborus and the answer from Andrew it was a little bit clear what I should do to try to concatenate both JSON files.

I began to change the code until I found [this example](https://codepen.io/nwbnwb/pen/MWewKme).
I began to work on that (as it uses some insights that the above cited fellows have suggested), cleaning up the code to try to understand what was going on and making some modifications, so that I could adapt to my own purposes. You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dbahiense/zLm14eh4/16/). Note that I changed some labels in the tooltip as I thought I was really understanding where each data comes from. But in a nutshell the result was still working.

Then it was the moment of truth and I had to replace the JSON files by my own files. I acted very conservative and in the Education/Election file I did just minor changes as you can see below. I made the original file smaller to 27 records and it was still working in part: we could see the USA map on the page and 27 counties highlighted in blue, while the others were, as expected, in black (tooltips stopped working as well) as we didn't have the data for them anymore. The error in the console was:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

I kind of expected this error, as long as I stay with the American topoJSON and not the Brazilian one.

After that one more change I did was finally put the "fips" values to mirror the values of the Brazilian topoJSON and not the American topoJSON. At this time no county was highlighted anymore and I thought (so naiv) that when I change to the Brazilian topoJson data everything would work out of the box.

See the [original](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json) and smaller Education/Election JSON:

```
[
    {
        "fips": 1001,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Autauga County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 21.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 1003,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Baldwin County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 28.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1005,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Barbour County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1007,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Bibb County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 10.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 1009,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Blount County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 1011,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Bullock County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 1013,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Butler County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 1015,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Calhoun County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 16.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 1017,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Chambers County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 1019,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cherokee County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.7
    },
    {
        "fips": 1021,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Chilton County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 1023,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Choctaw County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.8
    },
    {
        "fips": 1025,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Clarke County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 11.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 1027,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Clay County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 8.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1029,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cleburne County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 10.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1031,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Coffee County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 23.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 1033,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Colbert County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 17.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1035,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Conecuh County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 8.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 1037,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Coosa County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 9.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 1039,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Covington County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 1041,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Crenshaw County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 1043,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cullman County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 15.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 1045,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Dale County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 16.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 1047,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Dallas County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 1049,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "DeKalb County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 11.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 1051,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Elmore County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 21.4
    },
    {
        "fips": 1053,
        "state": "AL",
        "area_name": "Escambia County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.5
    }
]
```

And the same file mirroring the Brazilian topoJSON values:

```
[
    {
        "fips": 11,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Autauga County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 21.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 12,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Baldwin County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 28.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 13,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Barbour County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 14,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Bibb County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 10.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 15,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Blount County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 16,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Bullock County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 17,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Butler County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 21,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Calhoun County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 16.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 22,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Chambers County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 23,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cherokee County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.7
    },
    {
        "fips": 24,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Chilton County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 13.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 25,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Choctaw County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.8
    },
    {
        "fips": 26,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Clarke County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 11.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 27,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Clay County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 8.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 28,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cleburne County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 10.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 29,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Coffee County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 23.2
    },
    {
        "fips": 31,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Colbert County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 17.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 32,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Conecuh County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 8.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 33,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Coosa County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 9.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 35,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Covington County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.6
    },
    {
        "fips": 41,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Crenshaw County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 42,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Cullman County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 15.1
    },
    {
        "fips": 43,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Dale County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 16.9
    },
    {
        "fips": 50,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Dallas County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 14.5
    },
    {
        "fips": 51,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "DeKalb County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 11.3
    },
    {
        "fips": 52,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Elmore County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 21.4
    },
    {
        "fips": 53,
        "candidato": "AL",
        "area_name": "Escambia County",
        "bachelorsOrHigher": 12.5
    }
]
```

It really didn't work immediately and then I began to compare both topoJSON files. The critical part is the one bellow:

American file (see original [here](https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json)):

```
"objects": {
        "counties": {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "geometries": [
                {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "id": 5089,
                    "arcs": [
                        [
                            0,
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "id": 6079,
                    "arcs": [
                        [
                            5,
                            6,
                            7,
                            8,
                            9
                        ]
                    ]
                },
```

Brazilian file (see original [here](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v3/malhas/paises/BR?formato=application/json&qualidade=minima&intrarregiao=UF)):

```
"objects":{
    "BRUF":{
        "type":"GeometryCollection",
        "geometries":[
            {
            "arcs":[[0,1,2]],
            "type":"Polygon",
            "properties":{
                "codarea":"11"
            }
        },
        {
            "arcs":[[[3,4,5,-1]],[[6]]],
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "properties":{
                "codarea":"12"
            }
        },
```

As you see, in the American file we have **id** and in the Brazilian we have **codarea**. But unfortunatelly codarea is one level below in the file's structure inside **properties**. With that I tried to modify this part of the code to get these codearea values, but without success, changing id to `properties.codarea`, `properties[0]`, `codarea` only, but I have to say that I'm not quite sure anymore in what I'm doing... :-/

```
        .attr("fill", function (d) {    // set the color of the map region
            d.votos = data.get(d.id);   // according to the number of votes
            return colorScale(d.votos);
        })
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("cd-ibge", d => d.id)
        .attr("state", d => mapObjValues.get(d.id).state)
        .attr("county", d => mapObjValues.get(d.id).county)
        .attr("votos", d => data.get(d.id));
```

So, if you could help me to solve this puzzle I'd appreciate.

**======= EDIT II =======**
And here we go! :-)

As I reached 30.000 characters I can't develop this question. So I did a more specific one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660810/unable-to-get-property-from-topojson-automatically-using-d3-js-version-7) where I can show  the evolution of the problem.

Comment: `d.results` is an array of objects, whereas `d.properties` is just an object. In order to access `.tt_nominais` from one of those objects, you'd need, for example, `d.results[0].tt_nominais`.

Comment: @Ouroborus I change the text as it was wrong what I wrote. The correct in the code is always d.results.tt_nominais. I understand what you said that d.results is an array of objects while d.properties is an entire object. But if I have to use the index [0] and hard code this, it will catch only the first element, won't it? How I can make it read index 0 than index 1 and so on in this part of the code?

Comment: @Ouroborus by the way just log it in the console and the result was: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') 

        .style("fill", function(d){
                console.log(d.results[0].tt_nominais)
                return colorScale(d.properties.codarea);
        })

Comment: You'll need to rearrange the data before passing it into `.data()`. `d3.json()` just retrieves the data and hands you the resulting complex object. `.data()` expects an array so you'll need to combine the topographical and election data such that it ends up as an array of objects, where each object in the array contains the data needed to draw it.

Comment: The data comes from an external API. It's impossible to modify it.

Comment: You can modify it after you've received it.

Comment: I see that if you manipulate the data we can do this, but to stay in the scope of the question how was it possible to do it directly (using a json file and a CSV file) like in this cited example: http://bl.ocks.org/palewire/d2906de347a160f38bc0b7ca57721328

Comment: I mean "if we manipulate" ... "we can". ;-)

Comment: In election.json is `cd_ibge` the same identifier as `codarea`? If not - how does one match an entry in election.json to a feature in your topojson? Is there a common identifier?

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid. Yes, the cd_ibge is the same as the codarea. If cd_ibge = 33 in election.json there's a codarea = 33 in map.json.

Comment: Are you hoping to map presidential votes for any given party/candidate? And only for president? Or is there more to the elections file not shown that has other mappable dimensions?

Comment: Actually it should get only the tt_nominais from the first president in the list for each state. The values for the others will appear in a tooltip. That's why they're there too.

Comment: Something like president.results[0].tt_nominais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> console.log(d.results.tt_nominais) // this is undefined WHY??? <---

You bind geojson to your SVG elements with:

```
.data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.BRUF).features)
```

When you use `.attr("whatever", function(d) {`, the `d` refers to a single feature in your geojson (topojson.feature converts your topojson to geojson). So naturally, `d.results` will be undefined as you are not accessing any data from the elections json, only data for a single geojson feature.

There are a few solutions - all essentially accomplish the same thing in GIS terms, a join between your non-spatial data (elections.json) and your spatial data. This join is conducted using the common identifier for a region.

One option would be to create a JavaScript Map for your non-spatial data:

```
let map = new Map()
electionsData.president.forEach(function(d) {
  map.set(d.cd_ibge,d);
})
```

Now you can access the data for a district with: `map.get(codarea)` where codarea is a valid identifier (returning an item in the president array in your elections data).

This gives us:

```
   .style("fill", function(d){
        console.log(d.properties.codarea) // this gives us the expected codarea value
        // get the data for the region that indicated by codarea
        let region = map.get(d.properties.codarea)
        
        console.log(region);

        /* Do something with region data */

    })
```

Since you are only interested in the first candidate in the array for each area, we can use:

```
   .style("fill", function(d){
        console.log(d.properties.codarea) // this gives us the expected codarea value
        // get the results for that codarea
        let region = map.get(d.properties.codarea);
        let result = region.results[0];

        console.log(result);
       
        /* do something with result */

    })
```

Comment: Hi @andrew-reid, thanks a lot for your answer! I tried what you suggested but now I receive following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach'). And thought a lot about what you wrote and tried some possibilities. I just made an Edit to the question to explain better what is going on now. Using an american map I'm able to do the jog, but with the Brazilian data, not yet. And I change the approach, I will display only one candidate, as you mentioned. I think it's really what I need and not displaying all that data of all candidates.